# Strange log on Apache - how do I get rid of this?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

I have a Linode VM with Ubuntu, Apache2.

Right now, I have a large number of following lines in my /var/log/apache2/access.log file

```
www.example.com:80 223.96.144.128 - - [15/May/2015:11:30:13 +1000] "\x16\x03\x01" 400 0 "-" "-
```

Getting about 10 to 15 of these lines per second!

The thing is, I've removed "www.example.com" from Linode's DNS manager and I've disabled this domain on my apache configuration.

Why am I still getting it? and How could I remove it?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you have something talking SSL on a port that doesn't expect it. If you are expecting SSL, make sure your virtual host has `SSLEngine on`

Alternatively, you have this behind a reverse-proxy and have pointed https at the wrong port or have not stripped the SSL off.